# Can I use a function object without instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, function-object

Having the following code:

```
template<typename T, typename OutStream = std::ostream> struct print {
  OutStream &operator()(T const &toPrint, OutStream &outStream = std::cout) const {
    outStream << toPrint;
    return outStream;
  }
};
```

This call is erroneous:

```
print<int>(2);
```

Error message:

```
1>main.cpp(38): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'print<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

This call is not erroneous:

```
print<int> intPrinter;
intPrinter(2);
```

Can I use a function object somehow without its instantiation?
I cannot use a template function here, because I need partial specialization capabilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you want to say

```
print<int>()(2);
```

Here, the first parens create a temporary `print<int>` object by calling the (zero-argument) constructor, then the second parens actually invoke the function call operator on that object.  The error you're getting now is caused by the fact that

```
print<int>(2);
```

Is interpreted as a typecast expression to convert 2 into a `print<int>`, which isn't what you want (and also isn't legal).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

For those stateless wrapper classes, it might be better to use static member functions:

```
template<typename T, typename OutStream = std::ostream>
struct printer
{
    static OutStream & print()(T const &toPrint, OutStream &outStream = std::cout)
    {
        outStream << toPrint;
        return outStream;
    }
};
```

Then you can invoke them with `printer<Foo>::print(x);`, and you can typically supply a type-deducing helper function template:

```
template <typename T> std::ostream & print(T const & x)
{
    return printer<T, std::ostream>::print(x);
}
```

Now you can just say `print(x);`.

Comment: +1 Thanks. It's great. Your answer is very helpful and now I'm stuck with the answer selection...

Comment: @DaddyM: Pick whatever you feel helps you most. No worries :-)

Comment: This is the standard idiom for providing a set of functions that don't require state (such as you'd have in a functor object) to a template, specialized by type. The char_traits classes in the standard library are an excellent concrete example - they provide all the concrete behavior for the different character types for strings and streams.